# How to create a "buffer" delay for variable changes? ie. So a variable change is "transmitted" only after a certain amount of time?

Tags: c++, variables, buffer, delay, juce

I am very new to C++ and working in JUCE on some audio synth projects to learn.

I am using [this sinewave oscillator](https://github.com/micknoise/Maximilian/blob/master/maximilian.h) to create a pitched sinewave in JUCE quite simply like this:

```
  double oscOutput()
    {
        return testOsc.sinewave(frequency);
    }
```

JUCE transmits a frequency change to this sinewave when a new MIDI note is received like this:

```
 void startNote (int midiNoteNumber, float velocity, SynthesiserSound* sound, int currentPitchWheelPosition) override
    {
        frequency = MidiMessage::getMidiNoteInHertz(midiNoteNumber);
    }
```

I would like to implement some code in a new class/function that would delay the frequency change transmission by a certain number of samples/seconds. ie.

- `frequency` is assigned a change by the `startNote` function above.
- Delay object/function receives this new `frequency` value by `startNote` as well
- Delay object/function enters the value into a buffer and holds it there until a certain time (ie. loops `currentSampleIndex++` once each sample until `currentSampleIndex >= _____`)
- Once this point is reached, it can set `frequencyDelayed = frequency`
- Set oscillator to use this `frequencyDelayed` variable instead, and thus frequency changes to it will be delayed by ____ # of samples

Or, for example, this might look like this:

```
  double oscOutput()
    {
        return testOsc.sinewave(delayedFrequencyOutput());
    }

  double delayedFrequencyOutput()
    {
        return frequencyDelay.getOutput();
    }

 void startNote (int midiNoteNumber, float velocity, SynthesiserSound* sound, int currentPitchWheelPosition) override
    {
        frequency = MidiMessage::getMidiNoteInHertz(midiNoteNumber);
        frequencyDelay.setDelay(frequency, 0.05); //ie. (input, delay time in seconds)
    }
```

Is this a simple matter? How could one go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: It's usually easier to show what behavior you would like with code instead of explaining it in words. At least I don't really follow your explanation.

Comment: If I could code it, I wouldn't have to ask. lol. I basically want changes triggered by `startNote` to the `frequency` variable to be held in a buffer for a given length of time, then put into a new variable called `frequencyDelayed` once that time has passed. Then I can use `frequencyDelayed` to set the pitch for my oscillator, and the oscillator will have delayed pitch changes. Does that make sense?

Comment: I understand the general concept, but asking the question this way makes it very broad. There are many different ways to approach this depending on how you are planning to use it. If you show some psuedo-code just illustrating how it would be used in your code base it would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: Okay. I updated the question with as much as I can think might possibly work to explain what I'm trying to do further. If there are other ways, I'd be open to those as well. Any thoughts?